# AJAX post function not working properly after first call to the function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, post

I'm totally new to jquery and AJAX, After trying hard for 5-6 hours and searching the solution I'm asking for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").live('click',(function() {

            var data = $("this").serialize();
            var arr = $("input[name='productinfo[]']:checked").map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get();
            if(arr=='')
            {
                $('.success').hide();
                $('.error').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    data: $.post('install_product.php', {productvars: arr}),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(){
                        $(".productinfo").attr('checked', false);
                        $('.success').show();
                        $('.error').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }));
    });
</script>
```

and HTML+PHP code is,

```
$json = file_get_contents(feed address);
$products = json_decode($json);
foreach(products as product){
    // define various $productvars as a string
    <input type="checkbox" class="productvars" name="productinfo[]" value="<?php echo $productvars; ?>" />
}
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Install Product" />

<span class="error" style="display:none"><font color="red">No product selected.</font></span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"><font color="green">product successfully added to database.</font></span>
```

As I'm pulling the product information from feed, I don't want to refresh the page, that's why I'm using AJAX post method. Using above code "install_product.php" page is handling the string properly and doing its job properly.

The problem I'm facing is, when first time I check the check box and install the product it works absolutely fine, but after first post "Sometimes it work and sometimes it won't work". As new list is pulled from feed every first post is perfect after that I need to click install button again and again to do so.

I tested the code on different browsers, but same problem. What may be the problem?
(I'm testing the code on live host not localhost)

Answer (score 1):

`$.live` is deprecated, consider using `$.on()` instead.

Which function is not executing after it executes once? `$.live`?

Also, it should be:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

not

```
var data = $("this").serialize();
```

In your example, you are looking for an explicit tag called 'this', not a scope.

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {
    $(".submit")
        .live('click', function(event) {

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        var arr = $("input[name='productinfo[]']:checked")
            .map(function () {
            return this.value;
        })
            .get();
        if (arr == '') {
            $('.success')
                .hide();
            $('.error')
                .show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                data: $.post('install_product.php', {
                    productvars: arr
                }),
                type: "POST",
                success: function () {
                    $(".productinfo")
                        .attr('checked', false);
                    $('.success')
                        .show();
                    $('.error')
                        .hide();
                }
            });
        }

        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Comment: first of all thank you Barry for the answer. I changed $("this") to $(this) but when I canged $.live() to $.on() my code stopped working. You asked which function is not executing after is executes one? I'm not sure as I don't know Jquery/AJAX I found this code somewhere and customized myself according to my needs.

Comment: The code I given above is perfect in first attempt but not sure why it works randomly after first?

Comment: Continue using $.live, i saw you are using jquery 1.5. You should be fine.

Comment: If you are not dynamically generating any new input elements with event handlers bound to them, it will. `$.live` is mainly used to delegate event handlers to elements that do not yet exist in the DOM.

Comment: Basically I work in PHP and MySQL, I guess after first successive post "May Be" AJAX post or array something like that need to reset? just like Arrays in PHP, is there anything to reset the values like that? I hope this can give you a little hint

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, it is missing the value at arr and showing up the error or is it like it is making call but not returning or it is not reaching the call at all? 
Do a console.log to deal with debuging and check things out in firefox / chrome and see what and where is the issue.

Comment: I said everything is working fine except, it is failing to submit the product information in second call to the function. but after 2-3 attempts it install the products.

Comment: @prototype - try the piece I added